# Change direction of obstacles script unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform

I am trying to change the directions of the obstacles in this script from going across the screen horizontally to vertically. Here is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class ObSpawn : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject asteroidPrefab;
        public float respawnTime = 1.0f;
        private Vector2 screenBounds;
    
        // Use this for initialization
        void Start()
        {
            screenBounds = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(
            new Vector3(0f, 0f, -Camera.main.transform.position.z));
            StartCoroutine(asteroidWave());
        }
        private void spawnEnemy()
        {
            GameObject a = Instantiate(asteroidPrefab) as GameObject;
            a.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.y * -2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y * -1, screenBounds.y * -1));
        }
        IEnumerator asteroidWave()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(respawnTime);
                spawnEnemy();
            }
        }
    }
```

I do not know how to change the direction.
Here is the website I got the script from; the code is a bit different beacause it was not initially working the way I wanted it to.
https://pressstart.vip/tutorials/2018/09/25/58/spawning-obstacles.html
Hope you can help

Comment: The code you’ve posted spawns the asteroids but isn’t related to moving them. Code that moves the asteroids must be in a different file. (You may also need to change the spawning code to spawn them at the top or bottom of the screen instead of the side though.) Likely what you’ll be looking for is to change the asteroid’s y value (or add force on the Y axis) instead of the x value/axis.

Comment: As previous comment mentioned: the script you posted is unrelated to your question, if script to do so is written properly there is a chance you can change it only by changing serialized values.
Also on the side note: I suggest using Instantiate<GameObject>() instead of Instantiate() as GameObject - more elegant and less likely for weird bug in the code

Comment: so to change to spawn location to the top of the screen what would be the code

Comment: I guess I'll try to post it as an answer. Just mentioning in case it's useful to know: in the change you've made from `a.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.x * -2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y, screenBounds.y));` to `a.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.y * -2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y * -1, screenBounds.y * -1));` , the `* -1`s make no significant difference in this case but changing `screenBounds.x` to `screenBounds.y` only makes sense it you want to base the horizontal position on the vertical height of the screen for some reason related to differing aspect ratios.

Comment: 9:16 portrait...

Comment: Unfortunately the use of ViewportToWorldPoint() may be kind of confusing to get your head around, but basically `screenBounds = Camera.main.ViewportToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0f, 0f, -Camera.main.transform.position.z));` is giving you the world position of the bottom left corner of the camera view. Because the camera is centred at coordinates 0,0, the bottom left corner will be negative, e.g. if the screen space was 100 units wide and 888 units high, `screenBounds` would become `-50,-444`. This means multiplying them by -1 will give the other side of the screen at `50,444`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the code in the question covers spawning but not movement. Here's an attempt at an answer to your intended question based off the code from your link. Be aware that the code you're working from requires the camera to stay fixed at x=0, y=0.

In `SpawnEnemy()`, change:

```
    a.transform.position = new Vector2(screenBounds.y * -2, Random.Range(-screenBounds.y * -1, screenBounds.y * -1));
```

to:

```
    a.transform.position = new Vector2( Random.Range(screenBounds.x, -screenBounds.x), screenBounds.y * -2 );
```

And then **assuming your code is the same as the code at your tutorial link**, in Start() on the asteroids change:

```
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(-speed, 0);
    screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Screen.width, Screen.height, Camera.main.transform.position.z));
```

to:

```
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(0, -speed);
    screenBounds = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(0, 0, -Camera.main.transform.position.z));
```

(the screenBounds change is for consistency with your other code).

In `Update ()` on the asteroids change:

```
    if(transform.position.x < screenBounds.x * 2){
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
```

to:

```
    if(transform.position.y < screenBounds.y){
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
```

If you want to have both vertically and horizontally moving obstacles simultaneously that's a different problem.

Assuming the tutorial video explains the concepts used, I'd really suggest re-watching it and trying to understand what's actually being done and why. I'm kind of regretting having typed this out at the moment as it's avoiding the root issue, but hopefully being able to compare the various versions will be of some use to you.

Comment: How would i keep the clouds on the screen because sometimes they spawn half on half off?

Comment: Unfortunately that’s not very descriptive because this is the first mention of clouds and there are several things you could mean by keeping them on the screen. To change how far towards the edge of the screen the objects spawn or are destroyed, try multiplying the associated x (for horizontal) or y (for vertical) value by more or less, e.g. screenBounds.y * 1.2 for the destroy part, or screenBounds.y * -2.2 instead of -2.

Comment: @GCIreland
P.S. If you get errors when switching to decimal numbers, add an f to the end of them (e.g. 2.2f) to make them floats. A float is the type of floating point number Unity uses for most numbers supporting fractions.